# Automatically update data validation range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a drop-down list which change depending on another cell so if the other cell is set to `no` my other cell should have in a data validation range only `stand-by` if it's set to `yes` it should then have: `real`,`phone`,`both` everything works but...

my problem is that now I want to have a hundred others row in my array so I tried to extend the array but the data validation doesn't update. So I'd have to manually change one-by-one every data-validation cell.

Here is my sheet in the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZnLi.jpg (I've put a description on each image to make it more understandable).

*notice:* I know that in excel if I extend the array the data-validation works so I tried to extend it save it and then import it to google-sheets but it didn't work...and in excel there is no checkbox and some formula doesn't work so I've to keep it in google-sheets

*edit:* I know there is another post similar but it's not the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to achieve that is via VBA.

Steps:

1. Import "Yes" options in Range("A1:A4"). Range("A1") includes Yes as a header.
2. Select Range("A1:A4").
3. Home - Styles Tab - Format as Table - Select Light - Check range & Check "My table has headers".
4. Select "Yes" table - Design - Table Name: tblYes.
5. Import "No" options in Range("B1:B2"). Range("B1") includes No as a header.
6. Select Range("B1:B2").
7. Home - Styles Tab - Format as Table - Select Light - Check range & Check "My table has headers".
8. Select "No" table - Design - Table Name: tblNo.
9. Open VBA Editor. (Press ALT an then F11).
10. Double click on the sheet you want conditional formatting (from the box on the left up part of the page).
11. Select Worksheet from the left box above the code box.
12. Select Change from the right box above the code box.
13. Insert the below code and try.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("E1:E10")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then  '<- Change range if needed. Check if the change included in our range.

            Application.EnableEvents = False

                If Target.Value = "Yes" Or Target.Value = "No" Then '<- Case sensitive. Check the value insert if it is Yes or No

                    With .Cells(Target.Row, "F").Validation

                        .Delete '<- Clear previous valitation
                        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then '<- Check if the answer if Yes
                            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                            xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""tblYes[Yes]"")"
                        ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then '<- Check if the answer if No
                            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                            xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""tblNo[No]"")"
                        End If

                    End With

                Else '<- If the value insert is NOT Yes or No

                    .Cells(Target.Row, "F").Clear '<- Clear format & contents next to change cell
                    MsgBox "Insert Yes or No!" '<- Message box prompt for Yes or No

                End If

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet image including tblYes & tblNo:**

[image]

**VBA Editor image:**

[image]